# Bit Field Struct to int in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, bit-fields, reinterpret-cast

I have a struct with same type members in it. I am trying to convert it into `uint8_t` type. I am able to do that but cannot see the output please tell me where I am going wrong. Also I know there are another ways to do it? I am trying to do it this way because I want to get use to `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`.

Code is below:

```
int main()
{
    struct xs{
        bool x :1 ;
        bool y :1;
        bool z :1;
        uint8_t num :5;
    } zs;

    uint8_t* P = static_cast<uint8_t*>(static_cast<void*>(&zs));

    cout << *P << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are falling foul of the annoying fact that a `uint8_t` is in reality an `unsigned char`, so will be printed as some ascii character - quite likely not a visible one. Cast this up to some other integer type. But bear in mind what you are doing (treating a type as something it isn't) is horrible [**Undefined Behaviour**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), there are no guarantees whatsoever what will happen.

Comment: @BoBTFish Tried with char type still no output

Comment: As @BoBTFish says this is undefined behaviour.  The size and layout of `struct xs` is implementation defined and may not be a `uint8_t` in size.  Even if it was, what your casts are doing is defined to not work.  See __Notes__ in: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Comment: just a warning: maybe "getting used to" reinterpret cast isnt the best idea. reinterpret casts are for special circumstances and shouldnt be used too often, actually they are red flags that indicate that something weird is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. it is undefined behavior to access an object through a pointer to a type other than the type of the object. it works with most compilers, but technically your programm is allowed to do whatever it wants.
2. assuming we are not running into a problem mentioned in 1, my guess is that uint8_t is an alias for char, so cout will put a char onto your console. 
   you did not initialize the memory you are inspecting, so it can be 0. a char with value zero wont print out anything "observeable" in your console, look at the ascii table. try filling your struct with a 50 for example

Comment: _"you did not initialize the memory you are inspecting, so it can be 0"_ no, it will be uninitialized garbage.

Comment: I don't think it is UB. There is an exception for pointers of type `char*`, `unsigned char*` and `std::byte*`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely so techniccally it CAN be 0 :P sure, according to the standard its garbage. what i initially thought of was a compiler "extension" where the int would get zero initialized in debug mode only. i think i read it somewhere that visual studio did it? but i may be super wrong here. so i let it open to "it can be 0".

Comment: @Jens you are right. but is uint8_t always(!) aliasing char,unsigned char or byte?

Comment: @phön You are right. `std::uint8_t` can be any type that is exactly 8 bits, so even if `CHAR_BITS==8` it could be something else. `char` can also be larger than 8 bits (which would make `sizeof` interesting since it measures in multiples of `sizeof(char)`), and in this case `std::uint8_t` has ot be different. I have never seen this in real life.

Comment: @phon Please tell me with an example how to initzialise for the memory. thank You

Comment: you created an object of type `xs` with the name `zs`. so you can access the data with `zs.num = 40` for example

Comment: @Mandeep xs a{1,0,1,40};

Comment: @phön thank you. I now tried implementing int* P = static_cast<int*>(static_cast<void*>(&zs)); It works. However, if i define x as true than output is 1 but if i define y as true then output is 2. In which order it is working like that tthank You.

Comment: @phön I think i know its working in 8421 rule as on the basis of bit position it gives me a int number. But then y it does not work when trying to use char instead of int there.

Comment: what output do you wanna see/what do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

There a lot of problems here:

1. You seem to believe that `x`, `y`, and `z` will all pack into the single `uint_8`. This is not the case. "Adjacently declared bit fields **of the same type** can then be packed by the compiler into a reduced number of words"<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field#Implementation)</sup>
2. "The value of `sizeof(bool)` is implementation defined and might differ from 1"<sup>[[2]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Boolean_type)</sup> Therefore your `xs` will be implementation defined, but certainly not equivilent to `sizeof(uint_8)`
3. Because `xs` is not "similar" to a `uint_8` according to [the rules defined for C++'s type aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) the behavior of your `reinterpret_cast<uint_8*>` is undefined
4. Finally [as has been pointed out by many others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898424/struct-to-int-in-c#comment86812217_49898424) the reason that you can't see anything is that whatever implementation defined value is at `*P` it is likely a control character with no visible representation when treated by `cout` as a `char`

A possible workaround to the code you have would be to use these definitions:

```
constexpr uint8_t X = 0B1000'0000;
constexpr uint8_t Y = 0B0100'0000;
constexpr uint8_t Z = 0B0010'0000;
constexpr uint8_t NUM = 0B0001'1111;

uint8_t zs;
```

Then given that some value is assigned to `zs` you can perform these functions to output the former bit fields:

```
cout << ((zs & X) != 0) << endl;
cout << ((zs & Y) != 0) << endl;
cout << ((zs & Z) != 0) << endl;
cout << (zs & NUM) << endl;
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/duUKGe)

Comment: Thank you what u described in "1" is exactly what i wanted. I now tried implementing int* P = static_cast<int*>(static_cast<void*>(&zs)); It works. However, if i define x as true than output is 1 but if i define y as true then output is 2. In which order it is working like that tthank You.

Comment: I think i know its working in 8421 rule as on the basis of bit position it gives me a int number. But then y it does not work when trying to use char instead of int there.

Comment: Is there a reason you used `#define` for the constants? It seems to be a beginner's quesiton, so I would not show something that you shouldn't use.

Comment: @Mandeep I am afraid that at least I don't understand what you saying. What is 8421? Where do you use a char insteaf of int? There is no `int` in the code.

Comment: @Jens No particular reason. `const uint8_t x = 0B1000'0000` would have worked just as well as the `#define`s

Comment: @Mandeep I'm not sure what the 8421 number you speak of is, but that won't fit in a `uint8_t`/`char`.

Comment: @Jens By 8421 rule i mean "Binary-coded decimal" secondly i tried using int * instead of Uint * . it works "int* P = static_cast<int*>(static_cast<void*>(&zs));" It gives me output on the "Binary-coded decimal" value.

Comment: @Jens now when i try using char instead of int * it gives me no output

Comment: @Mandeep Note that as mentioned in **3** of my answer you may not cast a `struct xs` pointer to an `int` pointer. To do so would be undefined behavior.

Comment: @Mandeep I am still not sure I understand. Your approach with `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` is undefined behavior, as pointed out many times in comments in the answer above. It may look like it is correct because it behaves as you expect, but that is not guaranteed by the language semantics. http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html contains some usefull explanation. If you cast it to a `char` it may also not work because your struct may not fit into `sizeof(char)`, which is probably one byte.

Comment: @JonathanMee I am not getting. My question is simple that int pointer Works !!! but Char pointer does not work y

Comment: @Mandeep Maybe you need to open a new question because the text you posted in the question asks something else. But all answers are here in the comments and in the answer. Accessing something which is not an `int` through a pointer of type `int*` is undefined behavior (UB). It does something which may look correct, but another compiler or even just different compiler flags will do something else.

Comment: @Mandeep Hey I kinda agree with Jens that a new question would be helpful in understanding what you're asking. It's just hard to get it in the comments. If you could ask and link here I'll try to come help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that need to be solved here. First off, as some pointed out, you cannot access your object this way. If you want to construct a uint8_t properly, you would need to read the variables inside your struct and do some bit shifts, something like this:

```
uint8_t value = 0;
value |= (zs.x ? 1 << 7 : 0);
value |= (zs.y ? 1 << 6 : 0);
value |= (zs.z ? 1 << 5 : 0);
value |= zs.num;
```

Now, the second problem you are facing is that you're trying to output a number of 8-bits wide. By default, this is interpreted as a 'character' and will display as such. In order to accomplish what you want to do, you can either use a variable with a different length (uint16_t, uint32_t, ...) or use std::to_string.

```
cout << std::to_string(value) << endl;
```